# how to map dynamic list in a hash map in java

Tags: java, session

I faced a problem while working on a project, i have to find out the number of user with their name in a session id, while the session id generates dynamically and users also generate dynamically, we also dont the number of session id, and session id can be repeted. its a cycle of 5 min.
e.g.
let say user1 join in a session id 1. and again after 2 sec(cycle)
user2.....so many(dont know how many) join in session id 1.
after 5 min user1 join in session id 2. and again after 2 sec(cycle)
user2.....so many(dont know how many) join in session id 2.
after 5 min user1 join in session id 3. and again after 2 sec(cycle)
user2.....so many(dont know how many) join in session id 3.
..
..
..again after some time
some users join in a session id 1. and again after 2 sec(cycle)
some users.....so many(dont know how many) join in session id 1.
..
and so on
its a five day activity.
so on the last day i want to print out 
-> number of users join in a particular session id.
-> and the total number of session ids generated.

i tried to use the hash map with arraylist, but it didnot work out, as the number of session id is dynamic and are repetable, and the number of user joining in a session id are also dynamic,

so i could not find out how many Arraylist i have to created for users to store, and when user join the session id which is already have some users?

please suggest some ideas to implement it. and share some code if possible.....

Comment: It sounds like you have a design problem, you want to look up by sessionId but you reuse them so there is no way to know whether sessionId of `1` is the 1 you are looking for.  I suggest you have unique sessionIds so that when you look them up you know what you are looking for.

Comment: Sounds like a map of lists keyed on session ID but you say you've tried that so I'm curious as to why that didn't work. As @PeterLawrey says it's a bad design to have repeating session id's which are not logically the same session.

Comment: here, session id is kind of a Conference, so number of users join in the confrence, and the type of conference is reservation less(Means never end),